# Google colab download - ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, file, download, connection, google-colaboratory

I'm using google colab and I want to automatically download a file (which can be large : ~100Mo). For now, I'm using:

```py
from google.colab import files

files.download('results.zip')
```

But it is not consistent, and most of the time I get the error: `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer` :

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('::ffff:127.0.0.1', 55642, 0, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 320, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 351, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 418, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 406, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 639, in do_GET
    self.copyfile(f, self.wfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 800, in copyfile
    shutil.copyfileobj(source, outputfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfileobj
    fdst.write(buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 803, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

How can I fix this ? Or is there any work around to automatically download a file from colab ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For improved reliability, I'd recommend using the file browser in the left-hand pane rather than `files.download`, particularly if your file is large.

[image]

Another option is to mount your Google Drive and then copy the `results.zip` file there. Google Drive sync is also likely to be faster than direct download.

Comment: Hello, thank you :) I already know this work around but as I said, I would really need to download it automatically to the computer :/